# Codeigniter DX_Auth login not working after PHP update

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I recently upgraded PHP from 5.3.5 to 5.3.10. I'm using the [DX_Auth](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/DX-Auth) authentication library for Codeigniter. Now I have the following problems:

- Users who registered after the update cannot log in
- Users who changed their password after the update cannot log in anymore

Users who created an account before the update can still log in. DX_Auth uses PHPs `crypt()` function.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently DX_Auth generates longer hashes after the PHP update. Increasing the length of the password field in the DB did the trick.